# return value from ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to return value from ajax success function. but it is returning nothing.

JS

```
function calculate_total_percentage(course_log_id){
    var total_percentage = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url:"teacher_internal_exam_management/get_exams_of_course_log/"+course_log_id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (exams_of_course_log) {
            for (var x = 0; x < exams_of_course_log.length; x++) {
                total_percentage += parseInt(exams_of_course_log[x].marks_percentage);
            }
            alert(total_percentage);
            return total_percentage;
        }
    });
}
```

if i call like that

```
alert(calculate_total_percentage(course_log_id));
```

then showing '61' (due to call alert(total_percentage);) but 
then showing 'undefined' why? It should show '61' twice? What is the problem?

Comment: If I had £1 for each time this question was asked by someone who didn't search...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you have these and I'll have £1 for every delegation question.  Deal?

Comment: thanks everyone, i have a lot to learn...

Comment: Once you get a handle on asynchronous methods it's quite easy, and I've found it forces you to structure your code better as well.   Have fun :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function doesn't just wait until the ajax call is complete before exiting, so you need a way to handle the return value when it does arrive...

```
function calculate_total_percentage(course_log_id, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url:"teacher_internal_exam_management/get_exams_of_course_log/"+course_log_id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (exams_of_course_log) {
            var total_percentage = 0;
            for (var x = 0; x < exams_of_course_log.length; x++) {
                total_percentage += parseInt(exams_of_course_log[x].marks_percentage);
            }
            callback(total_percentage);
        }
    });
}
```

You can now pass a reference to a callback function which is to be executed after the ajax call succeeds...

```
function calculate_total_percentage_success(total_percentage) {
    alert(total_percentage);
}
```

Now you can call your original function like this...

```
calculate_total_percentage(id, calculate_total_percentage_success);
```

Comment: thanks i just got control of it.